# Why is my key not found when sending a JWT assertion to Azure AD?

Tags: bash, openssl, jwt, base64, signature

I'm trying to write a bash script to get access tokens from Microsoft for my app registered in AD.  I can't seem to get past this error though:

```
"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS700027: The certificate with identifier used to sign the client assertion is not registered on application. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: '356134 ...
```

The full gist can be found here: https://gist.github.com/smaring/3a3a6779a809beecc39624aada6e2b88

Here are some of the juicy bits ...

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in <your-app>.pfx -out <your-app>.pem
$ openssl x509 -outform der -in <your-app>.pem -out ${PUBLIC_CERT_FILE}
$ openssl rsa -in <your-app>.pem -out ${PRIVATE_KEY_FILE}

x5t="$(sha1sum ${PUBLIC_CERT_FILE} | awk '{print $1;}' | openssl base64 | sed s/\+/-/g |sed 's/\//_/g' |  sed -E s/=+$// )"

read -r -d '' HEADER <<EOF
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "x5t": "${x5t}"
}
EOF

HEADER_NO_WHITESPACE=$(echo "${HEADER}" | sed ':a; N; s/[[:space:]]//g; ta')
BASE64_ENCODED_HEADER=$(echo ${HEADER_NO_WHITESPACE} | openssl base64 | sed s/\+/-/g |sed 's/\//_/g' |  sed -E s/=+$// )

read -r -d '' PAYLOAD <<EOF
{
  "aud": "https: //login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  "exp": ${exp},
  "iss": "${CLIENT_ID}",
  "jti": "${jti}",
  "nbf": ${nbf},
  "sub": "${CLIENT_ID}"
}
EOF

PAYLOAD_NO_WHITESPACE=$(echo "${PAYLOAD}" | sed ':a; N; s/[[:space:]]//g; ta')
BASE64_ENCODED_PAYLOAD=$(echo ${PAYLOAD_NO_WHITESPACE} | openssl base64 | sed s/\+/-/g |sed 's/\//_/g' |  sed -E s/=+$// )

SIGNATURE=$( echo -n "${BASE64_ENCODED_HEADER}.${BASE64_ENCODED_PAYLOAD}" | \
             openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -sign <(cat ${PRIVATE_KEY_FILE}) | \
             openssl base64 | sed s/\+/-/g |sed 's/\//_/g' |  sed -E s/=+$// )

CLIENT_ASSERTION="${BASE64_ENCODED_HEADER}.${BASE64_ENCODED_PAYLOAD}.${SIGNATURE}"

curl -s -X POST \
        --header \"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" \
        -d \"\
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&\
grant_type=client_credentials&\
client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&\
client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&\
client_assertion=${CLIENT_ASSERTION}\" \
        https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting a Java version of this working I figured out that I was not generating the thumbprint properly.  The fix was this:

```
thumbprint=$(openssl x509 -in ${publicCertFile} -fingerprint -noout | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[2]}' )
thumbprintHex=$(echo -e "\\x${thumbprint}" | sed 's/:/\\x/g' )
thumbprintHexString=$(echo -e "${thumbprint}" | sed 's/://g' )

x5t=$(echo -ne "${thumbprintHex}" | openssl base64 | sed s/\+/-/g | sed 's/\//_/g' |  sed -E s/=+$// )
```

I have updated the gist to the fully working bash script.

Construct a JWT assertion in bash using client-credential with cert to get an access token from Microsoft Azure Directory --> https://gist.github.com/smaring/3a3a6779a809beecc39624aada6e2b88